# Expressing a problem generally through cartesian product

Tags: combinatorics

It's quite an easy problem, but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

> { { 1 } U { 2 } U { 3,  4 } U { 1 , 2 } U { 1 , 3, 4 } U { 2 , 3 , 4 } }

**Questions**:

This information will be in terms of a set of sets so I am thinking I can represent it with a function like the following:

> ```
> Let F be the set of farms,
> W the set of farmers,
> w works f to mean w attends to f
> so, F(w) = { f in F : w works f }.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is your set of farms, then the power set $\mathscr{P}(F)$ is the set of all possible collections of farms. For example, if there are three farms in $F$, then $\mathscr{P}(F)$ contains all the sets like $\{1\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{2,3\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{\}$, etc.

If there are some farms that must be worked together, you can define them as a subset $E\subseteq \mathscr{P}(F)$. For example, in your case, $E = \{\{1\},\{2\}, \{3,4\} \} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(F)$. You can think of this as a set of jobs. (A job is a set of farms that must be worked together.)

Now what about workers?  You could use the cartesian product if you like. But I think you may have better luck with *function spaces* than cartesian products. If $W$ is your set of workers and $E\subseteq \mathscr{P}(F)$ is a set of possible jobs then an assignment from workers to jobs is a function $\alpha:W\rightarrow E$.

The number of possible assignments is $|E|^{|W|}$. For example, in your case, there are three different jobs ({1}, {2}, or {3,4}). When there are two workers, there are $3^2 = 9$ possible assignments.

Suppose you want to know what farms are being worked on. The image $f(W)$, which is defined as $f(W) \equiv \{ f(w) : w\in W\} \subseteq E$, is the set of all jobs that are being worked on. You can take their union to get the set of all farms being worked on, regardless of who is working on them:

$$\left[\bigcup_{A\in f(W)} A \right] \subseteq F$$

This tells you which farms are being worked on for the assignment $f$.